Is it true that R(k+1, n+1) < R(k, n)?
Is the following statement correct or not:

The probability of having at least k+1 successes in n+1 trials is less than the probability of having at least k successes in n trials.

That is, is it true that $$R(k+1, n+1) < R(k, n)$$ where
$
R(k,n)=\sum_{i=k}^n\binom ni p^iq^{n-i}
$?

Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you
is grounds for closing.

This question looks like it requires an analysis of the cumulative Binomial distribution (which is an incomplete Beta function).  This can be difficult.  Fortunately, by examining the key concepts and exploiting only the basic axioms of probability, we can circumvent all that and as a bonus obtain a substantial generalization of the result.

Notation
For any number $j$ and trial count $m,$ let "$(j,m)$" be the event where exactly $j$ of the first $m$ trials are successes and "$(\ge j,m)$" be the event where at least $j$ of the first $m$ trials are successes.
Analysis of the events
Notice that
$$(\ge k,n)\ =\ (k,n)\cup(\ge k+1,n)$$
is a union of disjoint events (so their probabilities add).  Taking probabilities and solving for $\Pr(\ge k+1,n)$ gives
$$\Pr(\ge k+1,n) = \Pr(\ge k,n) - \Pr(k,n).\tag{*}$$
Observe, too, that the event $(\ge k+1,n+1)$ arises either because $(\ge k+1,n)$ has already occurred or $(k,n)$ occurred and the outcome of trial $n+1$ is a success (which we assume occurs with some probability $p$ when there are $k$ successes in the first $n$ trials).  This, too, is a disjoint union of events.
The probability calculation
Thus, exploiting $(*),$ we find
$$\begin{aligned}
\Pr(\ge k+1,n+1) &= \Pr(\ge k+1,n) + \Pr(k,n)\,\Pr((k+1,n+1)\mid (k,n)) \\
&= (\Pr(\ge k,n) - \Pr(k, n)) + \Pr(k,n)\,p \\
&= \Pr(\ge k,n) - (1-p)\Pr(k,n).
\end{aligned}$$
Since $p\le 1$ and $\Pr(k,n)\ge 0,$ the term subtracted from the right hand side is non-negative: that is, it can only make things smaller.  Consequently
$$\Pr(\ge k+1,n+1)\ \ge\ \Pr(\ge k,n),$$
QED.

It is amusing that nothing specific about the process is assumed: the trials don't need to follow a Binomial distribution and they don't need to be independent: $p$ is only the conditional probability of a success in trial $n+1$ given exactly $k$ successes in the first $n$ trials.
